# Nested Reduce with values in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

Good morning, after an *array.map* I have an array containing the same assignments with some nested ratings:

```
const assignments = [
    {
      name: "assignmentOne",
      difficultyRating: 1,
      funRating: 2
    },
    {
      name: "assignmentOne",
      difficultyRating: 3,
      funRating: 4
    },
    {
      name: "assignmentOne",
      difficultyRating: 5,
      funRating: 1
    }
]
```

Now I would like to get the total difficulty/fun rating, which would look like one of the following:

```
//Both the difficulty and fun rating in the same record
const assignmentsTotal = [
    {
      name: "assignmentOne",
      totalDifficultyRating: 9,
      totalFunRating: 7
    }
]

//Difficulty and fun rating as separate records
const assignmentsDifficultyTotal = [
    {
      name: "assignmentOne",
      totalDifficultyRating: 9
    }
]
const assignmentsFunTotal = [
    {
      name: "assignmentOne",
      totalFunRating: 7
    }
]
```

I'm pretty confident the best way to do this is using the *reduce* method.
After some digging around the only thing that came close to what I want to achieve is the following [article](https://medium.com/consol/nested-reduce-in-js-f91defcc74b3), yet I'm not able to get this to work properly. Is there a good way to do this from the starting point above, or would it be better to create separate arrays using *array.map* and after use the *reduce* method?

Comment: Hello, @ZeeAars! What code have you tried so far? Much like an educational setting, we prefer questions that show you work.

Comment: I totally forgot adding what I had tried so far, as I was trying to formulate my question as good as possible, my bad man.
So far I had tried using *forEach* to go one level deeper and making new sets/arrays(using *.map*) of the data provided above, tho everything I tried either returned *nan* or *undefined*. Which I thought had something to do with all assignments having a unique name(data is a mockup JSON with 10 students with 56 assignments, all of them with a fun and difficulty rating)
I will not forget to add my tests next time I want to ask a question and can still add some if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for same 'name' objects in array, below should be ok:

```
const reducer = assignments.reduce((total, current) => {
    return { name: current.name, difficultyRating : total.difficultyRating + current.difficultyRating, funRating : total.funRating + current.funRating } });
```

if you want to group objects by name, then look at lodash groupby function. In general, lodash is very handy in all array/obj functionalities.

Comment: I think you forgot to set the initial value of the accumulator for the `total` argument.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks a bunch man, both for the swift response and really clean answer :D

Comment: This solution works only if you have just one assignment (e.g. `assignmentOne`) but if you have more assignments (e.g. `assignmentOne` and `assignmentTwo`) it will sum the ratings of all assignments and use as name the one of the last assignment.

Comment: it worked with my array of 56 different assignments, all of them kept their original name and structure, so I'm not sure what you mean @secan

Comment: @ZeeAars, I created a code snippet to show what I mean here: https://jsfiddle.net/j014c67y/.

Comment: You are welcome @ZeeAars. if you have different assignment names, checkout lodash library and its grouby function. It's very useful library.

Comment: aaah I see, tho this is not a problem for me, as my mapped array contains a different array for every same name assignments, using a *forEach* to iterate over every set

Answer (score 0):

```js
const assignments = [{
    name: "assignmentOne",
    difficultyRating: 1,
    funRating: 2
  },
  {
    name: "assignmentOne",
    difficultyRating: 3,
    funRating: 4
  },
  {
    name: "assignmentOne",
    difficultyRating: 5,
    funRating: 1
  },
  {
    name: "assignmentTwo",
    difficultyRating: 5,
    funRating: 3
  },
  {
    name: "assignmentTwo",
    difficultyRating: 5,
    funRating: 1
  }
];

// if you want the totals as an array:
const assignmentsTotalArray = assignments.reduce((totalArr, item) => {
  // check whether the assignment is already in the array
  const assignmentIndex = totalArr.findIndex(elem => elem.name === item.name);

  // if the assignment is not in the array, add it and initialize the totals
  // otherwise update the totals
  if (assignmentIndex === -1) {
    totalArr.push({
      name: item.name,
      totalDifficultyRating: item.difficultyRating,
      totalFunRating: item.funRating
    });
  } else {
    totalArr[assignmentIndex].totalDifficultyRating += item.difficultyRating;
    totalArr[assignmentIndex].totalFunRating += item.funRating;
  }

  return totalArr;
}, []);

console.log('### assignmentsTotalArray:');
console.log(assignmentsTotalArray);

// if you want the totals as an object:
const assignmentsTotalObject = assignments.reduce((totalObj, item) => {
  // if the output object already contains the assignment, sum the ratings
  // otherwise create a new key for the assignment and initialize the ratings
  if (totalObj[item.name]) {
    totalObj[item.name].totalDifficultyRating += item.difficultyRating;
    totalObj[item.name].totalFunRating += item.funRating;
  } else {
    totalObj[item.name] = {
      totalDifficultyRating: item.difficultyRating,
      totalFunRating: item.funRating
    };
  }

  return totalObj;
}, {});

console.log('### assignmentsTotalObject:')
console.log(assignmentsTotalObject);
```